# Migrate worklight project version5.0.6 to version 6.0.0

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

After build all and deploy worklight project, it shows:

Failed to upgrade Worklight project 'CitizenCollaboration' to the latest platform version. [com.worklight.builder.sourcemanager.handlers.upgrade5_0.DeprecatedAppDescriptorElementsRemovalUpgradeHandler]

What's the problem cause it ?

Answer (score 0):

Something's not right in your application-descriptor.xl and the upgrader failed to address it.

Update your question with the complete application-descriptor.xml from your Worklight project and lets see which element should not be there or should be tweaked.